# issue with setOnItemClickListener"RecyclerView"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i am working in PopularMovies Project that i used the movies DB 
and i was successful fetch the data from the API but when i click the item in RecyclerView it doesn't work. 
I have followed the tutorial for udacity

PopularMovies-issue

[there is the link of the source code](https://github.com/elbhwashy/PopularMovies-issue)

and this is the adapter

What should I do?

```
package com.popmov.popmov.popmov

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView


import com.popmov.popmov.popmov.data.Movie;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    private Movie[] moviesData;
    public static final String BASE_URL_IMAGE = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342";

    private final MoviesAdapterOnClickHandler moviesAdapterOnClickHandler;

    public interface MoviesAdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onItemClickListener(int id, String title, String imageUrl, String synopsis, double rating, String releaseDate);
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(MoviesAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler,Context context) {
        moviesAdapterOnClickHandler = clickHandler;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public final ImageView imageView;

        public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_movie);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();

            int id = moviesData[adapterPosition].getId();
            String title = moviesData[adapterPosition].getTitle();
            String imageUrl = moviesData[adapterPosition].getImageUrl();
            String synopsis = moviesData[adapterPosition].getSynopsis();
            double rating = moviesData[adapterPosition].getRating();
            String releaseDate = moviesData[adapterPosition].getReleaseDate();

            moviesAdapterOnClickHandler.onItemClickListener(id, title, imageUrl, synopsis, rating, releaseDate);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutForItem = R.layout.movies_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutForItem, viewGroup, false);
        return new MoviesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String path = BASE_URL_IMAGE + moviesData[position].getImageUrl();
        Picasso.get()
                .load(path)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.poster)
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == moviesData) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return moviesData.length;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Check if the `onClick` method is called first, put a breakpoint or a Log statement.

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: You said that `onClick` doesn't work, so the first thing that you can do is to check whether `onClick` is even called, if it is called then it narrows down a problem a bit. You can check if it's called by either putting a breakpoint and running your app in debug mode. Or putting a `Log` statement inside the `onClick` method, something like that `Log.d("RecyclerView", "My onClick is called");`, run the app, click, and then check in LogCat, in Debug section whether you see the message or not, if it's there, that means the `onClick` is called and it has something to do with the code inside.

Comment: your `itemView` contains only `ImageView` ?

Comment: yes it contain only the imageView @AbuYousuf

Comment: Try to change `ClickListener` to `ImgeView`

Comment: Post your xml code

Comment: https://github.com/elbhwashy/PopularMovies-issue

Comment: this is the project @AbuYousuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `movies_list_item.xml` make  `ImageView` clickable to false

```
android:clickable="false"
```

As your `ImageView` clickable property was set to `true` so your `ImageView` are absorbing the `ClickListener`